# Characterizing surfaces in $R^3$ in which every point is an umbilic point

Tags: differential-geometry

How can it be shown that the only such surfaces are spheres or planes?

Comment: This is exactly Proposition 4 in section 3-2 in Do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces", P.147. You can find the full proof there.

Comment: I posted a proof at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141940/umbilic-points-on-a-connected-smooth-surface-problem/141945#141945